# How to browse users' accounts as an admin with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My app is built with Devise and sometimes some users report a problem, so I would like to be able so log in with their accounts and see the dashboard (the website in general) as they do (as a regular member).

How to do that with Devise? Is there any feature for this?

Comment: cancan + role_model ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `field role` to define user access. In case of other users just assign as `guest`. Make a admin role for your user entry. Now instead to logging into others account, create a custom option in dashboard which can be accessed only by admin, provide a option to change users which helps in viewing different dashboards depending on users.